# $\text{ A set} F \subset C(G, \Omega) \text{ is normal iff its closure is compact}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that :

$$\text{ A set}  F \subset C(G, \Omega) \text{ is normal iff its closure is compact}$$

By definition a set $F$ is normal if each sequence in $F$ has a sub-sequence which converges to a function $f$ in $C(G, \Omega)$.    Note that $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $C(G,\Omega)$ is a complete metric space.

One side is easy, for if I assume that the closure is compact, then let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence is $F$ and hence they are in $\bar{F}$ and the compactness of $\bar{F}$ implies that the limit lies in $\bar{F}$ (I am using limit point compactness here, for there is a metric on $C(G, \Omega)$).

For the other side :

Suppose that $F$ is normal. I take a sequence $\{f_n\} \in \bar{F}$. Now $\bar{F} \subset C(G,\Omega)$. I want to show that it is compact. Since $\bar{F}$ is closed, it is complete.Now for each $f_n$ there is a $g_n \in F$ such that $d(f_n,g_n) \lt \frac{1}{n}$ . Now each $g_n$ is in $F$ and $F$ is normal implying that it has a subsequence $g_{n_{k}}$ converging to $g \in \bar{F}$ (for it is closed).Now I show that $f_{n_k} \to g$ as $k \to \infty$. Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$. There is $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m}\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now for all $k \gt max\{k_0,m\}$ we have $d(f_{n_k},g) \le d(f_{n_k},g_{n_k})+d(g_{n_k},g) \lt \frac{1}{n_k}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \lt \epsilon $.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You don't really need to consider whether infinitely many $\{f_n\}$ are in $F$. Just approximate each $f_n$ with a $g_n\in F$ such that $d(f_n,g_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ and make a conclusion on $\{g_n\}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou This is what you meant right??

Comment: Looks good to me.